# Can't get a response of any kind from my NodeJs server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

When trying to connect to my NodeJs server i can't get a response of any sort. When trying to POST or GET from my Angular frontend to my Node/Express backend i get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE as noted below

```
angular.js:12011 OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/register net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE(anonymous function) 
@ angular.js:12011sendReq @ angular.js:11776serverRequest
 @ angular.js:11571processQueue 
@ angular.js:16383(anonymous function) 
@ angular.js:16399$eval @ angular.js:17682$digest 
@ angular.js:17495$apply @ angular.js:17790(anonymous function) @ angular.js:25890dispatch 
@ jquery.js:5201elemData.handle @ jquery.js:5009
registeruser.js:25 error saving to db
```

Even when i try connecting to the node server directly @ localhost:3000 , i get a timeout with the server not sending a response. i followed [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/user-authentication-mean-stack/) to guide me, and merged in some things to make it fit my needs and im not sure where i went wrong.

Server.js

```
// set up ========================
var DATABASE = "mongodb://localhost:27017/smartHomeDevices";
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); //require monogDB Driver
var morgan = require("morgan"); // log requests to the console (express4)
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); // pull information from HTML POST (express4)
var methodOverride = require("method-override"); // simulate DELETE and PUT (express4)
var passport = require("passport");
var _ = require("lodash");
var http = require('http');
//Create App
var app = express();
//Add Middleware for REST API
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json);
app.use(bodyParser.json({
    type: 'application/vnd.api+json'
}));
app.use(methodOverride("X-HTTP-Method-Override"));
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.use(passport.initialize());
//CORS Support, makes API Public

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    next();
});
//setup
app.models = require("./Models/moduleIndex");
//  Bring in the Passport config after model is defined
require('./config/passport');
//registering routes
var routes = require("./routes");
/*_.each(routes, function(controller, route) {
    app.use(route, controller(app, route));
});*/
app.use("/", routes);
//err handle
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// [SH] Catch unauthorised errors
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401);
        res.json({
            "message": err.name + ": " + err.message
        });
    }
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});
// Connect to the db
mongoose.connect(DATABASE);
mongoose.connection.once("open", function() {
    http.createServer(app, function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.url);
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.end();
    }).listen(3000);
    module.exports = app;
    console.log("Listening on 3000");
});
```

routes.js

```
//setup
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({
  secret: 'MY_SECRET',
  userProperty: 'payload'
});


var ctrlProfile = require('./Controllers/ProfileController');
var ctrlAuth = require('./Controllers/RegisterUserController');
// profile
router.get('/profile', auth, ctrlProfile.profileRead);

// authentication
router.post('/register', ctrlAuth.register);
router.post('/login', ctrlAuth.login);

module.exports = router;
/*module.exports = {
  "/smartDevices" : require("./Controllers/SmartDeviceController"),
  "/registeredUsers": require("./Controllers/RegisterUserController")
};*/
```

Comment: How is server.js being loaded?  I see that your `module.exports = app` will not work in server.js because it's inside an async callback.  So `module.exports` is not set when the module first loads.

Comment: If you put a `console.log()` inside the `mongoose.connection.once("open", function() {...})` handler, does it trigger?  Are there any errors in the console showing?  What debugging have you done and what did you learn?  This is a probably troubleshooting problem where you have to troubleshoot your own code rather than us just looking at it and telling you exactly what's wrong. So, the onus is on you to troubleshoot it and then ask us questions about what you find.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have console.log in the mongoose.connection.once and the statement is printed in the terminal. no errors are being thrown to the console which is what is puzzling. the only thing that lead me know it was nodejs problem was that my angular frontend worked fine except when trying to send a request to node. I used to postman to attempt to directly send post/get request to my node server and it gets the same error as my angular client : ErrEmptyResponse

Comment: Another issue is that `http.createServer()` only accepts one argument, not two so your second function you are passing is being ignored.  I'm not sure what it's there for anyway.   You didn't answer my question about how server.js is loaded?

Comment: I using sudo nodemon server.js; i removed the app in the http.createServer() and saved the return as a varible. i.e var server = http.. and printed out the object and logged server.listening and got this. its responding now so now i have to fix other small problems.